# int array to char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm working on C and I have a question.. I'm writing a program with Mcrypt and the decryption function require the chipertext at a char *pointer.
The problem is that the chipertext is filled with unknown ASCII symbols..
So I printf the chipertext with `%d` and I get chipertext in numbers like this..

```
23 -83 -48 -36 -49 -26 -16 -42 101 111 127 -46 -10 -3 -33 110 -106 29 -112 123 -21 43 50 81 70 -101 -71 94 -63 -122 52 76
```

My question is.. I take this chipertext and store it in to a `int array[32]`..
How can I copy the contents of this int array to my char *pointer?

Comment: If it's filled with ascii symbols, why do you store it in an `int array[]` and print as integers?

Comment: cauze some characters are not recognised and i don't get full chipertext..

Comment: Try your own to printf a -200 number to %c and you will see that you get same unknown symbols.

Comment: -200 is not a valid number for a `char` type, what the heck?

Comment: This is what i mean :D i guess the chipertext is supposed to be in numbers

Comment: No, you don't understand, that you are using a wrong type, and you tell me to do a totally pointless thing. You never got -200. All output is within <-127; 128> range which is fine for a `char` type. You probably should use it, and interpret as such, not integers. And why do you think after ciphering all character should be only within A-Z a-z 0-9 ?

Comment: ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ e o ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ n ▒  ▒ { ▒ + 2 Q F ▒ ▒ ^ ▒ ▒ 4 L

Comment: this is what i get in %c mode.. from the same numbers i wrote up..

Comment: Quit trying to print ciphertext as characters. There is no reason to expect ciphertext will be within the range of printable ASCII characters.

Comment: dude.. i'm not trying to print characters.. i just print it to %d

Comment: My question is .. that when i come back with this encrypted numbers.. i store them in to an int array .. and then i don't know to to pass them in to my char *pointer that is requiered for my decryption fuction... i mean.. i tryied srtncpy.. but it took only the first number..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to copy an array of `int` to an array of `char`:

```
int iarray[32];
char carray[sizeof(iarray)];

memcpy(carray, iarray, sizeof(iarray));
```

If `carray` is a pointer instead of an array, the code remains largely the same:

```
int iarray[32];
char *carray = addressOfSomeMemory;

memcpy(carray, iarray, sizeof(iarray));
```

However, the code above assumes your data is stored as `char`s packed into `int`s. If instead your data is stored one `char` per `int`, you need more code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    *(carray+i) = (char)iarray[i];
```

Comment: i played around wit the code you wrote above.. and solved my problem in 5 minutes... thx a lot Gregory..

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution for you would be to store your cyphertext in **char array[32]**.

Comment: not working... i've tryied this one.. int array takes the whole numbers array[0]= 23.... array[1]= -83.. but char array takes characters like this.. array[0]='2'.. array[1]='3'..array[2]=' '

Comment: @user3624383 In C, the `char` data type is simply a signed integer. You most certainly can assign numbers to it. `array[0] = 23` is perfectly valid.

Comment: How do you assign it? Can you share some code? By the way, Carey is right.

Comment: i get the message like this...     printf("Please enter your encrypted text: ");
    scanf("\n");
    for(k=0;k<32;k++) scanf("%d",&buf[k]);

Comment: and then .. i try to paste it on my char *pointer like this.. strncpy(buffer+1,buf, buffer_len);
But.. strncpy copies only the first number of my int array

Comment: I think you should share some more code (not here in comments). Edit your original question and add code to end of it with CODE tag.